Rescale Array in JavaScript or Python to a Specific Maximum Value and Target Sum
I'm working with a dataset in JavaScript (but can also be Python) and need some help with a math scaling problem. I would like to transform the values of an array so that the new array conforms to two constraints:

newMax: The maximum value of the new array should be equal to a specified value.
newSum: The sum of all elements in the new array should be equal to a specified value.

The transformation should maintain the relative proportions of the original values as closely as possible.
Given:

An array original of positive values.
The values for newMax and newSum.

Required:

A JavaScript function that creates a new array modified based on original, with the specified newMax and newSum.

function rescaleArray(original, newMax, newSum) {
  // Algorithm to be determined
}

// Example of usage
let original = [/* ...array of values... */];
let newMax = 48; // desired maximum value in the new array
let newSum = 68387; // desired sum of values in the new array

let modified = rescaleArray(original, newMax, newSum);

How can I approach this problem to find a suitable transformation? I'm specifically looking for an efficient algorithm or method that works with arrays.
What I have tried:
I have tried many algorithms, including the one below, but I can only hit the max or sum, never both. I also tried Linear Programming without any success. Below an example that can hit the max, but not the sum.
function rescaleArray(original, newMax, newSum) {
    let modified = original.slice();
    let currentMax = Math.max(...modified);
    let currentSum = modified.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  
    // First scale up/down to the new max
    let scaleToMaxFactor = newMax / currentMax;
    modified = modified.map(value => value * scaleToMaxFactor);

    // Now adjust the sum
    let iterativeScaleFactor = newSum / modified.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    let tolerance = 0.0001; // Define a tolerance level to avoid infinite loop
    let diff = Math.abs(newSum - currentSum);

    while (diff > tolerance) {
        modified = modified.map(value => value * iterativeScaleFactor);
        currentSum = modified.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        iterativeScaleFactor = newSum / currentSum;

        // prevent endless loop in case it is not converging
        let newDiff = Math.abs(newSum - currentSum);
        if (newDiff >= diff) {
          break; // the difference is not reducing anymore, break out
        }
        diff = newDiff;
    }

    // Final check to ensure the max is within the tolerance
    currentMax = Math.max(...modified);
    if (Math.abs(currentMax - newMax) > tolerance) {
        // Adjust for new Max again, if required
        scaleToMaxFactor = newMax / currentMax;
        modified = modified.map(value => value * scaleToMaxFactor);
    }

    return modified;
}


Are the values required to be integers?

If the resulting values can be floating point numbers, then you could use a linear projection.
You'll find the formula in the code below, together with an example run:


const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const max = (arr) => Math.max(...arr);

function rescaleArray(original, newMax, newSum) {
    const n = original.length;
    const currentMax = max(original);
    const currentSum = sum(original);
    
    const coefficient = (newSum - n * newMax) / (currentSum - n * currentMax);
    const constant = newMax - coefficient * currentMax;
    
    return original.map(value => coefficient * value + constant);
}

// Example run
const a = [110, 30, 71, 114, 28, 23, 96];
const b = rescaleArray(a, 200, 700);
console.log("max", max(b));
console.log("sum", sum(b));
console.log(b);



There is no check whether there is actually a solution.
If all values in the input array are equal, then the coefficient formula will divide by zero. When this happens when the output will include NaN values.
It could also be that the required sum is too great if even all array values would be made equal with the new maximum. In that case the required sum will still be attained, but the given newMax will actually be the minimum of the result array.
When values must be non-negative
For certain inputs, the values in the resulting array could be negative.  If we still want all values to be non-negative then we cannot achieve a linear mapping and must allow some deviation from that.
Linear mapping with exception for the maximum value
One way is the following approach, where the maximum value is excluded from the linear mapping as follows:

Remove the maximum value from this result
Apply a similar algorithm to get a new array, but this time with a required minimum, and give as target sum, the original target, but with the maximum removed (as we removed it in the previous step)
Inject the removed maximum back into that result.

Here is how that would look:


const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const max = (arr) => Math.max(...arr);
const min = (arr) => Math.min(...arr);

function rescaleArrayHelper(original, extreme, newExtr, newSum) {
    const n = original.length;
    const currentExtr = extreme(original);
    const currentSum = sum(original);

    const coefficient = (newSum - n * newExtr) / (currentSum - n * currentExtr);
    const constant = newExtr - coefficient * currentExtr;

    return original.map(value => coefficient * value + constant);
}

function rescaleArray(original, newMax, newSum) {
    const result = rescaleArrayHelper(original, max, newMax, newSum);
    if (min(result) >= 0) return result;
    newMax = max(result); // Re-getting it, to avoid floating point imprecission issues
    let i = result.indexOf(newMax);
    result.splice(i, 1); // Remove that maximum temporarily
    const result2 = rescaleArrayHelper(result, min, 0, newSum - newMax);
    result2.splice(i, 0, newMax); // Re-insert
    return result2;
}

// Example run
const a = [110, 30, 71, 114, 28, 23, 96];
const b = rescaleArray(a, 200, 500);
console.log("max", max(b));
console.log("sum", sum(b));
console.log(b);



This will keep the linear mapping for all values except the maximum, which will look like an outlier.

Thanks @trincot for this! You actually nailed the result given the constraints I provided, so I will accept the answer. However, I just realized that your algorithm provides negative values, which unfortunately I cannot have in my use case. If you find the spare time, let me know what adjustments I would have to make to add the constraint that all values must be >0.

I added a section to my answer.

Fixed an issue in the code that I added (second processing should not happen on original array, but on intermediate result).

Sorry, I thought I had a quadratic relation based solution, but it puts other values below zero. So I give up on it.

Thanks @trincot, you pushed the solution much closer!
